# CakePHP authentication and the User model

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on integrating authentication and authorization into my CakePHP application now and am having some difficulties.

First up, I'm not using ACL. <sub>It scares me.</sub>

In my AppController I have this:

```
var $components = array("Auth");
```

So, any time I want to check the logged in user, I call this from one of my controllers:

```
$this->Auth->user();
```

And I get an array which is the information from my `usrs` table (my table is called `usrs` with model `Usr`).

The issue is that I'll often want to call functions on the `Usr` model, so I have to do this in my controller:

```
$usr = ClassRegistry::init('Usr');
$usrInfo = $this->Auth->user();
$usr->set($usrInfo);
// -- or --
$usr = ClassRegistry::init('Usr');
$usrId = $this->Auth->user('id');
$usr->id = $usrId;
```

This doesn't seem very cakey and it's been bugging me since I know there must be a better way. Should I add `var $uses = array("Usr")` into my AppController so I don't have to use the ClassRegistry all the time? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Where you aware you could call the model User and set $useTable = 'usrs', or call the model Usr and set $useTable = 'usr' or 'users', or do you just not like the letter 'e'? :)

Comment: thanks for th advic dizl. I do hav some kyboard issus which i'm working through. ;) Anyway, I read in some blog that "User" is a reserved word in Oracle (which I'm using now for the first time) - the Oracle connector isn't the best-tested piece of code I've seen, so I thought it better to just avoid the issue altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just [`use`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/53/components-helpers-and-uses) the model?

```
// in Controller
var $uses = array('someModel', 'User');
```

This makes the model available as usual:

```
$this->User->someFunction($this->Auth->user('id'));  // for example
```

Comment: would that work if I put it on the AppController? It wouldn't overwrite the default value? (eg: PostsController by default has `$uses = array("Post");`)

Comment: $uses will load the Usr model for all actions, the loadModel approach will only load it when needed. So it's a toss up really between more objects in memory or more code in controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered one way to do it in one line:

```
$this->loadModel('Usr', $this->Auth->user('id'))
```

I still don't know if this is best practice though...

Comment: `Controller::loadModel` is best practice for controllers if you only need the model for that controller action and not all actions in the controller. Outwith controllers you would need to resort to `ClassRegistry::init` and `App::import`, and when using those you should ask yourself if you are still following MVC. This post sums up Gwoo's stance on these approaches: http://techno-geeks.org/2009/05/models-inside-controller/